# Vue - Invalid type: 'container' must be a String or HTMLElement."

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am using the sample code in my **body**:

```
<div id="mly" ref="mlyRef"></div>
```

And **javascript** code:

```
if (this.$refs.mlyRef instanceof HTMLElement) {
    var mly = new Viewer({
        accessToken:"",
        container: this.$refs.mlyRef,
        imageId: "",
        component: { cover: false }
    });
}
```

Any idea what might be generating the following error - Invalid type: 'container' must be a String or HTMLElement."

Comment: Might be a problem with the `this` keyword scope. Try assigning 'this' to a `that` variable before the object instantiation

Comment: make console.log(this.$refs.mlyRef) and see <div data-v-7ffc20cf="" id="mly"></div>

Comment: Have you tried using `#mly` instead as a value for the `container` ?